# Injecting Connection String into DbContext Class using Autofac in a TopShelf Service (.Net Framework)

Tags: c#, autofac, dbcontext, topshelf

I'm creating a service that needs to reference legacy DLLs for our ERP system so unfortunately .NET framework is how I need to do this.  I tried using a Core Worker Service but my calls to the DLLs won't work.

I like using TopShelf and looked up DI to use with this and Autofac seems to be the way to go and it has TopShelf support.  I don't like keeping any settings in our config files so that it's easier to deploy to other environments.  We have a whole system that keeps settings tied to the environment you are in (dev, test, prod, etc...).  In Core apps I simply inject the connection string in the startup and all is well.  In this app I want to inject the connection string when I start the service and be able to spin up a DbContect class at anytime and have it use that connection string.

Since I scaffold my data layer and didn't want to modify the generated DbContext, so I created another partial class (MyContext.Custom.cs) with a constructor that allows me to pass in the connection string

```
 public MyContext(string name) : base(name)
    { }
```

In my Program.cs I'm adding in an Autofac container to TopShelf

```
HostFactory.Run(serviceConfig =>
    {
        serviceConfig.UseAutofacContainer(container);
        // etc...
    }
```

The container is being built in a function, I tried following many examples but I can't seem to get my constructor with the parameter to be the one that is used.  Here are a few of the ways I've tried.  Each method produces no error but it runs my default constructor where it is looking for the named connection string in the config file.

```
static IContainer BuildContainer()
{
    string myConnectionString = AppConfig.Instance.Settings["MyConnectionString"];

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    //builder.RegisterType<MyContext>()
    //    .UsingConstructor(typeof(string))
    //    .WithParameter("name", myConnectionString)
    //    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    //builder.Register(c => new MyContext(myConnectionString)).As<MyContext>();
    //.WithParameter("name", myConnectionString);

    //builder.RegisterType<MyContext>()
    //    .WithParameter("name", myConnectionString)
    //    .AsSelf();
    //.InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    builder.Register(c => new MyContext(myConnectionString)).AsSelf();

    builder.RegisterType<MainService>();
    return builder.Build();
}
```

I've tried each variation with .As and .AsSelf().  I've put in the .InstancePerLifetimeScope() and also left it out.  I'm not really sure what to set the scope to in this case but figured it should work with lifetime.  No matter what I've tried I can't seem to get it to use my constructor.

If I've left out any information feel free to ask and I can fill it in.  Hopefully someone has done this.  I guess I could pass in the connection string everytime I instantiate a DbContext but I was hoping to get it to work like a Core app which is so much nicer.

thanks

EDIT:
Adding code to show how I'm using my DbContext

```
public bool Start()
{
    using(var db = new MyContext())
    {
        var warehouse = (from w in db.Warehouses
                         where w.WarehouseCode == "ABCD"
                         select w).FirstOrDefault(); 
    }
    // other code...
}
```

Comment: Could you show us an example of a class (e.g. `MainService`) that depends on the DbContext? Then perhaps we can help identify the issue..

Comment: I added that code above into the start function of my MainService since the normal spot I hit my database is in another project and has many layers to get to it.  I get the same error of not being able to find the connection string name in the config.  Also the default constructor is being hit rather than my custom constructor.  Hope this helps.

Comment: ugh, guess I'm passing my connection string down the chain, feels so dirty.